# drag items from toolbox not working vs2022 .net 6 & 7 winform

Tags: winforms, .net-7.0

We were trying to create a winform application , Vs2022 and .Net7.

Tried for .Net 6 as well, its the same

But we were not able to drag&drop or double click to add the control to forms.

Can anybody give any pointers to fix this

VS 2022 version : Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current

Version 17.4.4
[image]

after doing Right-click the Toolbox and turn off Show All below is the screenshot of toolbox, All Windows Forms group option or item itself is not showing up as in the screenshot below

[image]

Comment: Right-click the Toolbox and turn off `Show All`. What remains? In case you still don't see usable Controls (you have Web Elements there), post the content of your `.csproj` file

Comment: Thanks Jimi for your response , Cs projfile content   for your ref <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>

Comment: You should know that any update must be added to the body of the question, not in comments -- You didn't say what happened when you set off `Show All`. Do you have Controls under the `All Windows Forms` group?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34516078/visual-studios-toolbox-is-empty

Comment: Close VS, delete the hidden `.vs` folder that's in the Solution's main directory. Restart, reset the Toolbox. If you still don't see your Controls, there's something wrong with the installation

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/8539) on Microsoft GitHub:

> Choose Toolbox items is not supported in .NET core yet.
>
> posted by: [dreddy-work](https://github.com/dreddy-work) commented on Jan 30

Note: Yes, I'm pissed too.